# What feature of Autodesk Inventor is used to bring in a vector image and use it as part of your part?

Tags: vector, metal, autodesk-inventor

I'm using Autodesk Inventor to create sheetmetal designs for cut out on a plasma cutter cnc table such as an electrical box.   After laying out a sheet in the sketch, I'd like to import a vector based image like a DXF which might be a logo, clipart design, etc., resize it and use it in cutting the design out of the sheet metal.

What feature/function of Inventor will allow you to do this?  Are you aware of any tutorials that show this type of functionality?

Comment: Go to "open" and then check the drop-down list for file type. There is a list here: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-general-discussion/what-types-of-files-can-be-imported-into-inventor/td-p/4311903 ). I don't use the software, but I see that DXF is listed

Comment: That makes the entire drawing the object.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here - [Import AutoCad data into Sketch](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/InventorLT-Help/files/GUID-541DB455-8FC7-4CEC-BC4C-E270864217E4-htm.html).  It uses the ACAD button to import a DXF file or similar into a sketch.

I also found this video that covers it in depth.  [Autodesk Inventor Import](https://youtu.be/fp5HvqH8gK8)